# Notifications for comments not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-notification

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giw1i.png)

I am trying to send notifications of the event when some likes and comment on his post, notifications for comments and likes working
here is my notification class.
i have error in my CommentController `if ($event->user_id != $comment->user_id)`

```
class NewCommentEvent extends Notification
{

    use Queueable;
    protected $comment;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'comment' => $this->comment,
            'event' => Event::find($this->comment->event_id),
            'user' => User::find($this->comment->user_id)
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

My controller function code for notifications on comments

```
 public function store(CommentRequest $request)
    {


        $event = Event::findOrFail($request->event_id);


        Comment::create([
            'comment' => $request->comment,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'event_id' => $event->id
        ]);

        if ($event->user_id != $comment->user_id) {
            $user = User::find($event->user_id);
            $user->notify(new NewCommentEvent($comment));
        }



        Toastr::success('Comment post with success','', ["positionClass" => "toast-top-center"]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

my CommenRequest

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CommentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'comment' => 'required|max:2000',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Is there any problem with all that code?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller: the variable `$comment` is not defined.

From Laravel docs:

**The `create` method returns the saved model instance.**

so the solution is:

```
$comment = Comment::create([
            'comment' => $request->comment,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'event_id' => $event->id
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined your $comment, you just created a comment. This is throwing the error

```
$comment = Comment::create([
     .
     .
]);
```

This will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

The error message was clear. `$comment` is undefined. Replace your controller code with the follow:

```
public function store(CommentRequest $request)
    {


    $event = Event::findOrFail($request->event_id);

   // defined comment here
    $comment = Comment::create([
        'comment' => $request->comment,
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'event_id' => $event->id
    ]);

    if ($event->user_id != $comment->user_id) {
        $user = User::find($event->user_id);
        $user->notify(new NewCommentEvent($comment));
    }



    Toastr::success('Comment post with success','', ["positionClass" => "toast-top-center"]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```